# Asp.net with MVC multiple model in one view (create, update)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have problem in asp.ne Mvc with multiple model in one view on create and update
I 'm work on exams system 
class Questions and class Answers
Question is aparent class and Answers is a child class

```
[Bind(exclude("id"))]

class Quesions
{
public string question{get; set;}
public Datetime Timepostquestion{get; set;}
}
[Bind(exclude("id"))]
class Answers
{
public string answer{get; set;}
public Datetime Timepostanswer{get; set;}
public questionId {get; set;}
}
```

in a view I use two classes how to use classes in insert and update
what a way which I have to solve my problem

Answer (score 7):

You should wrap the two objects in another object for the View, commonly referred to as a **"ViewModel"**.

```
public class QuestionAnswerViewModel
{
   public Question Question { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Bind to that in your View.

Then use something like **AutoMapper** to map it back to your two entities.